# How can I redirect all my external links to a splash screen using php

Tags: php, redirect, splash-screen, external, steam

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve!
If any of you skilled users could help me with this using php, I would be forever grateful!

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8S1OQ.png)

It's pretty much a notice page to warn a user they are leaving the site!

Comment: What have you figured out so far? You will obviously need to ... 1. modify your outgoing URLs to be sent as a variable to the splash screen, and 2. display a splash screen, where you give the actual link. It's really pretty basic, give it a try first and update your question with whatever code you came up with.

Comment: Ok, so with variable , that would only work for specific allocated links correct? Example, i would have to manually set the variable to the link for it to redirect to the splash. But what I really want is, when a user shares a link on my website, i want that link to be picked up by the splash. Informing users they are being redirected to a whole new page!

Comment: You would change it on the fly when you output the link, it doesn't matter what the link is. If you output the link directly as `<a href="https://example.com">` the only way to "intercept" it at that point is attaching a `click` event with JS to user-shared links that does the `href` modification to `?url=https://...`.

Comment: You're a genies!